# Suppressing PDO Warnings

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, exception, suppress-warnings

I'm trying to display a server status, based upon whether the database can be connected to or not.  With the old school `mysql_connect()` and `mysqli_connect()` it was easy.  I'm trying to stay modern, so I'm using PDO, but I can't figure out how-to suppress the default warning.  From what I can tell, you need to use the `getMessage()` function for it to print the PDO warning, but I'm not using it.

Here's my code:

```
8  $dbstatus = 1;
9  try {
10  $db = new PDO($dbms . ':host=' . $dbhost . ';port=' . $dbport . ';dbname=' . $dbname, $dbuser, $dbpasswd);
11  $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
12 } catch(PDOException $e) {
13  $dbstatus = 0;
14 }
15 if($dbstatus == 1) {
16  echo '<span style="color: green">DB Up</span>';
17 } else {
18  echo '<span style="color: red">DB Down</span>';
19  exit;
20 }
```

All the connection variables are supplied and correct, except the `$dbhost`, which is intentionally broken to test this.  Now, it produces the desired results, but is also prints a warning message too:

> **Warning**: PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in **C:\xampp\htdocs\cd\includes\dbconnect.php** on line **10**

If I correct the `$dbhost` variable, it works fine, so I know the issue isn't with the PDO statement being usable.

Any ideas on what I'm missing?

**Solution**

I used a variation of what was supplied by jeroen:

```
if(filter_var(gethostbyname($dbhost), FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)) {
 $dbstatus = 1;
 try {
  $db = new PDO($dbms . ':host=' . $dbhost . ';port=' . $dbport . ';dbname=' . $dbname, $dbuser, $dbpasswd, array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
 } catch(PDOException $e) {
  $dbstatus = 0;
 }
} else {
 $dbstatus = 0;
}
if($dbstatus == 1) {
 echo '<span style="color: green">DB Up</span>';
} else {
 echo '<span style="color: red">DB Down</span>';
 exit;
}
```

Thank you for the help and I hope this helps someone else! ^^

Comment: Inside an ajax call that returns a json the warning (seems to be un-catchable) is rendering my two last days of work useless. This sucks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing I can see here, is that you tell PDO to throw exceptions *after* you have tried to open the connection. That is most likely too late.

What you could do instead, is send that option to the constructor directly using the 4th parameter:

```
try {
  $opts = array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  $db = new PDO($dbms . ':host=' . $dbhost . ';port=' . $dbport . ';dbname=' . $dbname,
                $dbuser, $dbpasswd, $opts);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
...
```

That will probably solve your problem.

**Edit:** If the host name is provided by the user, you could validate it before sending it to the PDO constructor.

For example using:

```
if (filter_var(gethostbyname($user_provided_host_name), FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)) {
  // valid hostname / ip address
}
```

That will work for domain names, `localhost` and ip addresses.

Comment: Changing the attributes declaration didn't prevent the warning from loading.

Comment: @AoN Strange, I have not tested exactly the same, but I get exceptions here (using the ip address of google.com...): http://codepad.viper-7.com/dLZi8R

Comment: I think I see where it's having trouble.  I'm breaking the connection by adding a space in the middle of the address, and it is producing the error off of that.  When I put in a proper domain (google.com) or IP address, it doesn't produce the warning.  Using a mistyped "localhost" or IP gives the warning.  It's great for a tech, but not so much for a user that just wants to know if the DB is up.  Know anyway to compensate for this?  I tried `rawurlencode()` on the `$dbhost` variable, but that did nothing for the warning. :S

Comment: @AoN To avoid the problem you might have, you could validate the host name, see my edit.

Comment: Still no change to the error when wrapping the `try catch` in the `if` statement.

Comment: @AoN You shouldn't wrap the `try catch` in an `if` statement, you should validate your user-provided variables before you use them.

Comment: I've tried that too.  Here's the Viper-7: http://codepad.viper-7.com/jT18m4  Substituting a "proper" IP or domain name prevents the warning from appearing and only displays the "DB Down" message needed.  Add a space or put a non-standard domain name (no top-level domain) and it gives the unwanted warning.

Comment: @AoN You missed the part in the filter function where I filter for a valid ip address: http://codepad.viper-7.com/fuHEeF. If you don't use that, you filter for a string so `l ocalhost` remains `l ocalhost`.

Comment: omg, I feel so stupid now!  Thank you for your patience and help!  It worked great, even with my original variation of wrapping the `try catch` in the `if` statement. :)