# php pdo suppressing connect warning

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

When i connect to the database, i try to handle the error that the database is down. But i seem to be unable to suppress this warning:

```
Warning: PDO::__construct() [pdo.construct]: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in * on line 29
{"status":false}
```

what should be there:

```
{"status":false}
```

the code for the error handling:

```
try
{
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$db}", $us, $pw,array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
} 
catch(PDOException $ex) 
{
    echo '{"status":false}';
}
```

The PDO errormode is set to PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION so it should not throw a warning at all. It should throw a fatal error that i can catch..

the problems seems to be that it throws this warning if it cannot solve the dns

Solution at an @ to suppress the warning

```
  @$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$db}", $us, $pw,array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
```

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132759/php-catch-exception-and-continue-execution-is-it-possible)?

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26533274/suppressing-pdo-warnings)?

Comment: Technically it's not PDO's problem. it's the underlying getaddrinfo call that' failing. You'd have to disable PHP warnings to suppress that.

Comment: @MarcB thx post as answer so i can accept

Comment: @PhilippZiehe it (`@`) is known as the [Error Control Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php).